# Fetch particular string from particular block

Tags: c#

I am new to c#. I have text file with data in it but I want to read particular block line data.

Here address can occur multiple times in text file.

```
Something here...
... ... ...  
    interface "system"
        address 10.4.1.10/32       
        no shutdown
    exit
something here...
... ... ...
    address 101.4.1.11/32
```

but i want to capture within this

```
interface "system"
        address 10.4.1.10/32       
        no shutdown
    exit
```

I want to capture this ip from the block:

```
10.4.1.10
```

I tried this code:

```
int counter = 0;
string line;
// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine (line);
   counter++;
}
file.Close();
// Suspend the screen.
Console.ReadLine();
```

Expected Output:

my expected output is to capture the ip address from that block ie.10.4.1.10
that ip is inside "interface system" block.. that makes that address as unique.. as there can be many ips with keyword address. So i want to take address which is inside interface system block.

Please let me know how i can capture particular string from the block.

Comment: What is your expected output? What is it about that block that makes it unique amongst the other blocks that may or may not be in the text file?

Comment: @Heretic Monkey my expected output is to capture the ip address from that block ie.10.4.1.10.

Comment: that ip is inside "interface system" block.. that makes that address as unique.. as there can be many ips with keyword address. So i want to take address which is inside interface system block.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that information.

Comment: I've edited the answer for your edited question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regular Expressions are perfectly suited to handle this type of "problem". The following console app demonstrates how to use `Regex` to extract the desired IP address from the targeted string block.

```
private static readonly string IPV4_PATTERN = "[0-9./]";
private static readonly string IPV4_IPV6_PATTERN = "[A-Z0-9:./]";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TestSearchFile();
}  

private static string ParseIpWithRegex(string textToSearch, string startBlock, string endBlock)
{
    var pattern = $@"{startBlock}\D*\s*({IPV4_IPV6_PATTERN}+).*{endBlock}";
    var ms = Regex.Match(textToSearch, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (ms.Groups.TryGetValue("1", out var g))
    {
        return g.Value;
    }
        return string.Empty;
    }

private static void TestSearchFile()
{
    var sep = Environment.NewLine;

    var ipAddress6 = "2001:db8:85a3:8d3:1319:8a2e:370:7348";
    var ipAddress4 = "10.4.1.10/32";

    var t = "Something here..." + sep;
    t += "... ... ... " + sep;
    t += "interface \"system\"" + sep;
    t += "address " + ipAddress4 + sep;
    t += "no shutdown" + sep;
    t += "exit" + sep;
    t += "something here..." + sep;
    t += "address 101.4.1.11/32" + sep;
    t += "... ... ... " + sep;

    var startBlock = "interface \"system\"";
    var endBlock = "exit";

    var ip = ParseIpWithRegex(t, startBlock, endBlock);
    Console.WriteLine($"IP: {ip}");
}
```

I've included two IP address patterns `IPV4_PATTERN` for IPV4 only as well as `IPV4_IPV6_PATTERN` for both IPV4 and IPV6. Select the one you feel is most appropriate. Although the `IPV4_IPV6_PATTERN` would apply to both IP versions I believe it improves performance slight when the search is narrowed by using the narrowest pattern.

Don't forget to import the `Regex` reference:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

---

**Code Explained**

The method "ParseIpWithRegex" uses a `Regex` pattern constructed by using the string that signifies the start of the targeted block and the string that signifies the end of that block. Nestled within that pattern is the regular expressions class definition that defines the IP address pattern we wish to isolate as a group.

```
$@"{startBlock}\D*\s*({IPV4_IPV6_PATTERN}+).*{endBlock}";
```

***It should be noted that the curly brackets are just for string interpolation and have (in this case) nothing to do with the actual regular expression!***

After the "startBlock" we see "\D*". This means that after the "startBlock" include in the search all non-numeric characters (where the "star" indicates to expect zero to infinitely many). Then we see "\s*" which means to include all white space (including new line characters since I included `RegexOptions.Singleline`).

The IP address pattern is in brackets "()" which instructs `Regex` to create groups. In this case, behind the IP address pattern (in the above code example `IPV4_IPV6_PATTERN`) there is a "+" symbol. This indicates that there MUST be at least one of the characters that is in the IP address Regex class definition in order to be considered a "match".

After that we see ".*" in front of the "endBlock". This means to look for any character--including the "new line" character (zero to infinitely many) in from of the "endBlock" string.

If you have any questions, please leave a comment.

---

**EDIT**

From your button `onclick` method you will call `SearchFileForIp`. You will need to change `myTextBox` to match your code.

You should also decide whether you will be searching IPV4 or both IPV4 and IPV6 and select the appropriate variable `IPV4_PATTERN` or `IPV4_IPV6_PATTERN`.

```
private void SearchFileForIp()
{
    var fileName = "c:\\test.txt";
    using var sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
    string fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();

    var startBlock = "interface \"system\"";
    var endBlock = "exit";

    var ip = ParseForIpRegex(fileContent, startBlock, endBlock);
    myTextBox.Text = ip; //Change this to match your code
}

private readonly string IPV4_PATTERN = "[0-9./]";
private readonly string IPV4_IPV6_PATTERN = "[A-Z0-9:./]";
private string ParseForIpRegex(string textToSearch, string startBlock, string endBlock)
{
    var pattern = $@"{startBlock}\D*\s*({IPV4_PATTERN}+).*{endBlock}";
    var ms = Regex.Match(textToSearch, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if(ms.Groups.Count > 0)
    {
        return ms.Groups[1].Value;
    }

    //For .Net Core apps
    //if (ms.Groups.TryGetValue("1", out var g))
    //{
    //    return g.Value;
    //}

    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: if i want to implement this code in windows form .Net  (Visual studio) what changes need to be made in it that after clicking button it should show that ip???

Comment: I am getting error for TryGetValue as: "'GroupCollection' does not contain a definition for 'TryGetValue' and no accessible extension method 'TryGetValue' accepting a first argument of type 'GroupCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Take a look at the new edit. This code should work for you.

Comment: Thanks alot. It worked :-) Accepted your answer it helped me.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the 2 answers with Regex solutions, If address line comes always after `interace "system"`, than a simple for loop can do the job.

```
interface "system"
    address 10.4.1.10/32       
    no shutdown
exit
```

So We go thorugh file lines and check if line is `interace "system"` than take the next value and parse it to string of ip address.

```
public static string GetIpAddressFromFile(string fileName, string startLine)
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
    var ipAddress = string.Empty;

    for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        var line = lines[i].Trim();

        if (line != startLine) continue;
        var addressLine = lines[i + 1].Trim().Replace("address", "");
        ipAddress = addressLine.Substring(0, addressLine.IndexOf("/", StringComparison.Ordinal));
        break;
    }

    return ipAddress.Trim();
}
```

Lets assume you that your file is inconsistent and address does not comes first after `interface "system"`

```
interface "system"
    ...
    address 10.4.1.10/32       
    no shutdown
exit
```

So in this case we put all lines between `interface "system"` and `exit` in list of strings, Or dictionary and fetch the address key.

```
public static string GetIpAddressFromFile(string fileName, string startLine, string endLine)
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
    var ipAddress = string.Empty;
    var state = false;
    var results = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var t in lines)
    {
        var line = t.Trim();
        if (line == startLine)
            state = true;

        if (line == endLine)
            state = false;

        if (!state) continue;
        var s = line.Split(" ");
        results.TryAdd(s[0], s[1]);
    }

    var result = results.GetValueOrDefault("address");
    if (result != null)
    {
        ipAddress = result.Substring(0, result.IndexOf("/", StringComparison.Ordinal));
    }

    return ipAddress;
}
```

Usage:

```
var startLine = "interface \"system\"";
var endLine = "exit";
var ip = GetIpAddressFromFile(@"File.txt", startLine);
//Or
var ip = GetIpAddressFromFile1(@"File.txt", startLine, endLine);
```

Both methods are tested with your given example and return:

```
10.4.1.10
```

Answer (score 3):

If the *start* of the block and the *end* of the block are well defined, in order to find the block you can simply:

1. Search for the start of the block
2. Do something with the lines until the end of the block

---

```
string line;
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");

while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null && !line.Equals(START_OF_BLOCK)); // 1.

while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null && !line.Equals(END_OF_BLOCK)) // 2.
{
    // do something with the lines
}

file.Close();
```

---

### Updated answer after edited question:

In order to "extract" the string in a form of an IP address inside the block, you could, for example, use [Regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) with a .NET [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netcore-3.1) class, with previously finding the needed block:

1. Search for the start of the block
2. Search for the line inside the block which contains `"address"`
3. Extract the IP address from the line using `Regexp.Match()`

---

```
string line;
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
string pat = @"\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\b";
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pat);

while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null && !line.Equals(START_OF_BLOCK)); // 1.
while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null && !line.Equals(END_OF_BLOCK)) // 2.
{
    if (line.Contains("address"))
    {
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match ip = reg.Match(line);
        Console.WriteLine(ip);
        break; // break if you are sure there's only one ip in that block
    }
}

file.Close();
```

Comment: if i want to implement this code in windows form .Net  (Visual studio) what changes need to be made in it that after clicking button it should show that ip???

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple LINQ for that:

```
var textData = File.ReadAllLines("Path goes here");
var address = string.Join("", textData
.SkipWhile(x => !x.Trim().StartsWith($"interface \"system\""))
.SkipWhile(x => !x.Trim().StartsWith($"address"))
.Take(1)).Split("address")[1].Trim();
```

1. SkipWhile goes trough string array until it finds line which starts
   like:  "interface \"system\"".
2. Second SkipWhile goes trough part after "interface \"system\"" string until 
   it finds line which starts like:  "address".
3. Then you Take(1) matching line and create string out of it.
4. Then you use Split to create new array which contains address text
   and ip address.
5. After that you simply take last part of the array.